# Using Macros for Defining Class Member Fields with Extra Actions (C++)

Tags: c++, macros

Could someone help me for the following situation:

Within a class definition, need to define any number of certain type of member fields with their specific actions automatically called when an instance of this class created . Like,

```
class C {
}
class F1 {
public:
   int check(C* host);
} 
class C1:public C {
public:
   C1() { this->pre_checks();   }
   F1 m_a1;
   F1 m_a2;
public:
   void pre_checks() { // use inline solution
      m_a1.check(this);
      m_a2.check(this);
   }
}
```

In the above case, class C1 contains two fields of F1 type. So in C1's function pre_checks(), each field will perform its extra action "check()" automatically when an instance of C1 is created.

Field number could be any or non. A class C2 could:

```
class C2: public C {
public:
   C2() { this->pre_checks();  }
   F1 m_t1;
   F1 m_t2;
   ...
   F1 m_tn;
public:
   void pre_checks() { // use inline solution
      m_t1.check(this);
      m_t2.check(this);
      ...
      m_tn.check(this);
   }    
}
```

How can I use a macro, say MDEF_FIELD, to do like this:

```
class C3: public C {
   MDEF_FIELD  m_b1;
   MDEF_FIELD  m_b2;
   ...
   MDEF_FIELD  m_bn;
}
```

and the class C3 definition will also contain the code for:

```
m_b1.check(this);
m_b2.check(this);
...
m_b3.check(this);
```

and they are automatically performed each time an instance of C3 is created.

Thanks

Comment: What is `check` meant to do, that can't be done in the `F1` constructor?

Comment: "Check() actually needs be passed in the C1, C2 or C3 object. I just did editing to make them in correct sense.

Comment: Still would like to understand what `check` actually does - at least conceptually. It seems like your question is an "XY question", where you have a problem X, and you think the solution is Y, when actually you should be asking how to solve X.

Comment: Why do you add a field to class instead of using vector of objects (or, maybe better) pointers ?

Comment: @Mats: May be you are right. The problem is actually, that 
class C1 need to register a specific type of fields and need to be done at the C1 object creation time. But I could not do it by using macros. I must add each extra code for each such a member field. I'd like to use macro to do it and just do like this:
  MDEF_FIELD (F1, m_field1)

Comment: @borisbn: Because 1)in other code, those fields are just like ordinal C++ fields and referenced by using hard/static code; 2)vector using pointers. Not easy to control for pointer problems.

Answer (score 0):

This looks/sounds like a real problem to me (honestly, the word "mess" came to mind). I'd (strongly) advise trying to find some entirely different approach if at all possible.

If you really need to do this, a macro is almost certainly the wrong way. The right way (to the extent that's not just an oxymoron) is a somewhat convoluted class structure: first, an F1_proxy, which is what the clients will actually work with. In most respects this will be a simple pImpl kind of thing that just forwards its functionality to an F1 object it "owns".

Where it'll differ is that the proxy class will contain a static vector of pointers to instances of F1. Each time you create an F1 proxy, it'll walk through the current vector and do the "check" on each instance. Assuming that succeeds, it'll then create an instance of F1 and add it to the vector. When you destroy the F1 proxy, it'll destroy the associated F1 object *and* remove the pointer to that F1 object from the static vector, so it'll no longer be checked when other objects are created.

I feel obliged to repeat, however, that while (I think) this meets what you've stated as your requirements, the requirements strike me as quite problematic. It'll do what you say you want, but it strikes me as unlikely to be a good solution to the real problem (whatever it is).

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I considered your proxy solution carefully and think it will not work for my case.

These classes F1 and C, C1 etc will be a code base/library to other programmers, the problem here is actually a coding problem, not a runtime logic one. Using macros to do this (if possible) would hide the low level logic to behind and other coder would just do their jobs as normal. Even if the proxy solution succeed the business logic, but still needs add extra code for each class like C4, C5 the other programmer created. They would not understand why but also it's tidious ...

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper class.

```
class F1_autocheck : public F1 {
public:
    F1_autocheck(C *p) : F1() { this->check(p); }
};

class C1 : public C {
public:
   C2() : m_t1(this), m_t2(this), ..., m_tn(this) { }
   F1_autocheck m_t1;
   F1_autocheck m_t2;
   ...
   F1_autocheck m_tn;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Still, as I mentioned to Jerry, this is a coding literal problem, not a runtime business logic one.
From your solution, when defining field m_t1, you need add extra code piece m_t1(this), m_t2(this) for m_t2 field, etc. This is extra code. I'd like to hide them behind. So, doing 
   `MDEF_FIELD  m_t1`
 will not only put
     `F1_autocheck m_t1`, but also put the code 
     `m_t1(this)` inside the constructor

Comment: @duney But at least if you forget one of the two steps, you get a compiler error. (And this is all runtime behavior. `check` is called at runtime, not compile time.) Macros confuse IDEs (and humans). If you really want to use a macro, you'll have to do the X macro trick.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I think if `m_t1(this),` being forgot to write, the compiler will not complain. I have tried lot of macro solutions but no luck. I realized that I am actually asking C++ language for extra semantics, i.e. **write some new syntax at one place, the result will affect several places for code pieces**. So far, I haven't seen any solution for it. 
Really hoping could get a solution on macro for this

Comment: @duney The compiler will complain if you forget to write `m_t1(this)` because `F1_autocheck` has no default constructor. As I noted, if you want a macro-based solution, you can use an X macro.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you gave F1 extra restriction. In my case, F1 object could be created outside C, and also by using default constructor. Seems I need specify more details for classes F1 and C, C1, C2 etc. Not sure if I need to recap my question. Maybe, my question should be describe as: In a class, fields of type F1 be defined and also specific actions be performed 4 each field when the object created. Low level logic will hide behind, others use macros to define such fields of any class inherited from C. X macro couldn't do it as #define clause can't be inside another macro.

Comment: The `F1` object can still be created outside `C` without a default constructor. It is `F1_autocheck` that does not have a default constructor. The rule for C++ is "special actions when an object is created are specified in the constructor." You can still use an X macro where the X macro says `X(m_t1) X(m_t2) ... X(m_tn)` and you then `#define X(t) t(this)` when constructing and `#define X(t) F1 t;` when declaring members. But an X macro is probably going to be more confusing than helpful here.

Comment: Could you expose an example for using X macro to both define a member field `F1_autocheck m_t1` and meanwhile do `m_t1(this)` in the ctor or whatever actions in a function definition for this field, BY USING ONE MACRO? And also I can use this macro to define another similar field.

Comment: I gave the definitions in the previous comment.